# Is 360 degree 3D live streaming supported with live streaming api

Tags: youtube-api

I sent 360degree 3D streaming data( Top & Bottom ) using live streaming api.
But youtube does not automatically recognize the streaming data by 3D.

I think I should send type of streaming data like "projection"( 360/rectangular )

Are there any related options in the provided properties? ( ex) 2D / 3D )

Answer (score 0):

Youtube app has support for [360-degree live streams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) according to Techcrunch but the [Livestreaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) has yet to catch up as there are no mention of 3D operations in the official docs.